# Java Iterate through list of objects

Tags: java, list, loops, object

I'm a beginner in Java Programming and having hard time understand the concept of loop through list of objects in Java.

Input data records are of the form:

```
    TestDataSet1 |4|01-category1|100|43|||
    TestDataSet2 |4|02-category2|10044307001|0|100|2016-07-20 21:36:00|
    TestDataSet3 |4|03-category3|104331|
    TestDataSet4 |5|04-category4|100|2016-07-20 21:36:00|
    TestDataSet5 |4|01-category1|100|43|||
    TestDataSet3 |4|03-category3|104331|
```

In order to read the above records data in my program based on category, created of list of objects for each category as:

```
List<Object> category1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4;
```

If input data is of the form,

```
TestDataSet1 |4|01-category1|100|43|||
TestDataSet2 |4|02-category2|10044307001|0|100|2016-07-20 21:36:00|
TestDataSet3 |4|03-category3|104331|
TestDataSet4 |4|04-category4|100|2016-07-20 21:36:00|
```

accessing list of objects can be done with:

```
 Category1 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(0);
 Category2 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(1);
 Category3 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(2);
 Category4 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(3);
```

So, looping can be done as:

```
 for(int index=0 ; index = list.size(); index++){
 object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(index);
 }
```

But at times, some of the category data will be missing and input will look like:

```
case1: 
TestDataSet1 |4|01-category1|100|43|||
TestDataSet3 |4|03-category3|104331|
TestDataSet4 |5|04-category4|100|2016-07-20 21:36:00|
```

or

```
case2:
TestDataSet1 |4|01-category1|100|43|||
TestDataSet3 |4|02-category2|104331|
TestDataSet4 |5|04-category4|100|2016-07-20 21:36:00|
```

It is understandable that in case1 the data can be accessed in :

```
 Category1 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(0);
 Category3 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(1);
 Category4 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(2);
```

or in case2:

```
 Category1 - object.getcategor1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(0);
 Category2 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(1);
 Category4 - object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(2);
```

I'm confused on how can I make the 'for loop' generic to cover all these cases in looping through the list of objects:

```
 for(int index=0 ; index = list.size(); index++){
 object.getcategory1Orcategory2OrCategory3OrCategory4().get(???);
 }
```

Comment: The problem is unclear to me. Have you tried just reusing your first loop? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data seems to be a `|`-separated text file, with up to 8 values per row, so you create a class, e.g. called `DataSet`, with 8 fields, then create a list of those for storing the rows, i.e. `List<DataSet>`.

You can then loop the list using an enhanced for statement:

```
for (DataSet dataSet : list) {
    // now get values with calls like list.getName()
}
```